# Sound won't play in Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: kubuntu

I can't get sound to work in my computer that I just installed Kubuntu 12.04 on. I've tried to switch between the two audio options in the sound settings, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you include some more *specific* information in your question? What relevant hardware are you using? (`lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 audio`) Have you applied all system updates (manually check in system updater, install all, reboot)? Do you hear anything when running `speaker-test` (in a terminal)? Also please post the output of `amixer` (long output, you may want to post that on paste.ubuntu.com).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know I shouldn't post this as an answer, but I couldn't see a place to add a comment. Thanks!

Here's the result for:  lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 audio

```
john-hill@john-hill-E-4100:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 audio
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) AC'97 Audio Controller [8086:24d5] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device [107b:2019]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_intel8x0
        Kernel modules: snd-intel8x0
01:00.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Creative Labs SB Audigy [1102:0004] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Creative Labs SB0090 Audigy Player/OEM [1102:0058]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_emu10k1
        Kernel modules: snd-emu10k1
john-hill@john-hill-E-4100:~$
```

Here's the result of: speaker-test

```
john-hill@john-hill-E-4100:~$ speaker-test

speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 192 to 2097152
Period size range from 64 to 699051
Using max buffer size 2097152
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 524288
was set buffer_size = 2097152
 0 - Front Left
```

Here's the result for: amixer

```
john-hill@john-hill-E-4100:~$ amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Master Mono',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-46.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone Jack Sense',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Line',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch cswitch cswitch-exclusive penum
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [off] Capture [off]
  Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [off] Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Line Jack Sense',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'CD',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch cswitch cswitch-exclusive penum
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [off] Capture [off]
  Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [off] Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined cswitch cswitch-exclusive penum
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Left: Capture [on]
  Front Right: Capture [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost (+20dB)',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Select',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Mic1' 'Mic2'
  Item0: 'Mic1'
Simple mixer control 'Video',0
  Capabilities: cswitch cswitch-exclusive penum
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Front Left: Capture [off]
  Front Right: Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Phone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined cswitch cswitch-exclusive penum
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Left: Capture [off]
  Front Right: Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Aux',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch cswitch cswitch-exclusive penum
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off] Capture [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off] Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mono Output Select',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Mix' 'Mic'
  Item0: 'Mix'
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 15
  Front Left: Capture 8 [53%] [12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 8 [53%] [12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mix',0
  Capabilities: cswitch cswitch-exclusive penum
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Front Left: Capture [off]
  Front Right: Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mix Mono',0
  Capabilities: cswitch cswitch-exclusive penum
  Capture exclusive group: 0
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Front Left: Capture [off]
  Front Right: Capture [off]
Simple mixer control 'External Amplifier',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Stereo Mic',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
john-hill@john-hill-E-4100:~$
```

Comment: I found the fix on UbuntuForums.com. Here's the link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2112520

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue too but I was able to find an easy fix outside of terminal. I tried all the information I found online (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2238366) <- is a good summary, BUT NONE of it worked.

I followed this,

Click Sound Icon on Bar

IGNORE THE DROP DOWN MIXER, IT LIES!

Select "Mixer" to manually open "KDE Mixer - Playback Devices"

For some reason, mine had my Built in Analog (headphone jack) turned all the way down. It also didn't help trying to designate it in System Settings. This KDE Mixer seems to be the trick.

Hope it helps!

-Simpleton Tricks